# Critique Chat Times

Tags: discussion, critiques

We had our first [critique chat](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/461/chat-critique-sessions) yesterday, and it went pretty well.

If you missed it and would like to see the transcript, we [have it bookmarked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/14/photographic-memories?tab=conversations) so it's easy to find.

*Scheduled Times*

Going forward, we need to know what days/times are best, and most importantly, when we can have the largest group available.

Please suggest a time and/or vote for any time that you would be willing/able to drop in.

I'll use this as a guide as I try to set the schedule.

Also, please list times using [UTC time](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=1440)

Comment: So... Is anyone interested in these, or other times?

Answer (score 2):

Wednesday UTC 18:00

Answer (score 2):

Any day, between 0200-0800 UTC (6pm to midnight US-Pacific).

Answer (score 1):

Sunday UTC 21:00

Comment: trying this one out... Nov 28. 2010

Answer (score 0):

Saturday UTC 1500 (morning US, mid-day UK)