# What topic would you like to see as the basis for a chat event?

Tags: discussion, critiques, chat, events

The [photography chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/14/photography) has been a little bit quiet lately. While it's definitely okay for people not to use that feature, and it's a busy time of year for a lot of people, I thought it might be fun to have a scheduled chat event.

This would provide an opportunity for new users to a) discover that we have a [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/14/photography) if they don't already know, and b) get to know the more established members of the community. Who knows, it may even spark ideas for questions to be asked on the main site, or inspire blog posts for the [Photography community blog](http://photo.blogoverflow.com/). :)

So the question is: **What should the topic of a chat event be?**

The other issue to be considered is what time the event should be. I'd like to maximize the ability of all users to join, recognizing that it's [impossible to schedule a time that's good for everyone](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/478/critique-chat-times) based on how international this group is.

Previous scheduled chats have been centered around [photo critiques](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/461/chat-critique-sessions), but we're open to anything. Leave your proposed topic as an answer (one topic per answer, please!) and the community can vote on what appeals to them.

Answer (score 5):

### Photo Critique

An opportunity to talk about all that subjective stuff that isn't really appropriate on the main site. Post a photo, tell us what you liked/didn't like/want help with, and get feedback from the rest of the community.

Answer (score 5):

### Artificial Lighting 101

Tips and insight from our local membership about how to start using artificial lighting, such as flash, to illuminate a scene. Sub topics that could be covered include what the different types of light and shadow are, how to position flashes to achieve certain kinds of shading, how to effectively use bounce, how to start small on-flash diffusers, and how to use large diffusers and umbrellas.

Answer (score 4):

### Your Favorite/Most Inspiring Photographer

Can be either current or historical. We can discuss why you like them, what you find inspiring about them, post links to examples of his/her work, and talk about how he/she may influence your own work. A great way to find new inspiration and learn something about photographic art!

Comment: This is scheduled for the 21st November at 18:30 UTC (19:30 CET) - more details at http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/14/photography?tab=schedule

Comment: The chat event happened, and while small, gave us exposure to some great photographers! Chat transcript, complete with images and links, can be found here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/14/photography?tab=conversations

Answer (score 4):

## Digital Photographic Development Q&A

A question and answer session allowing our membership to ask all the questions they have about digital photographic development and processing techniques. Cover things like how to use Lightroom to do basic development, using Photoshop curves for creative effects, and similar topics.

Comment: I think this is a great idea: Does anyone (@jrista or anyone else) feel comfortable leading this event if we schedule it soon? Or do we need to try to have a guest come in and lead it? It can be informal...maybe we can set up a separate meta thread for digital photographic development questions that people have ahead of time so whoever's leading it can make sure they have answers prepared / we know that there's something to talk about?

Comment: If we do schedule it and I'm to lead it, it would have to be at a time I'm not at work. Historically, most chat events here have been scheduled smack in the middle of my work day, and I can't dedicate time to them most of the time.

Answer (score 2):

### Breaking Into Portraiture

Tips and insight from our local membership about how to break into portrait photography for novices, or even insight from prior novices who have learned from their mistakes and are beginning to get the hang of things, but still have fresh perspectives on how they learned their newfound techniques.

Answer (score 1):

### Nature Chat

A casual chat about nature photography, covering participating members insights, epiphanies, tips and techniques about capturing nature in its element...from expansive wide-angle landscapes to fantastic wildlife shots to the macroscopic microworld.